# AutoMapper - MapFrom gives me the following error: expression tree cannot contain assignment operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I've been using AutoMapper successfully for a while now. However, when I use MapFrom() in the CreateMap calls, I get the above error.

I have upgraded to version 2, and it seems the registries have been broken.

```
CreateMap<EmailInbound, EmailMessageModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Subject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Subject = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Subject) ? "No Subject" : src.Subject)));
```

Any ideas what has broken here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do an assignment in lambda expression instead of returning a value. Here's the fixed version.

```
CreateMap<EmailInbound, EmailMessageModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Subject, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Subject) 
                                                         ? "No Subject" 
                                                         : src.Subject));
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw on their site: http://automapper.org/blog/2011/09/22/automapper-20-released/ it shows this as breaking change: MapFrom is Expression-based only. Use ResolveUsing for Func support. Is this the reason for it breaking?

Comment: Penny has dropped! The assignment was not required, but v2 must have highlighted this as an error whereas v1 didn't. Thanks again.